TIMER0 NORMAL_MODE Settings on AVR_ASM: Doesn't work as a delay on ATmega328P
.text
;define_addr
.org 0x000
.equ TCCR0A, 0x24
.equ TCCR0B, 0x25
.equ TCNT0,  0x26
.equ OCR0A,  0x27
.equ OCR0B,  0x28
.equ TIMSK0, 0x6E
.equ TIFR0,  0x15
.equ DDRB,   0x04
.equ PORTB,  0x05

/*
--ticks=second/(prescaler*1000/cpu_clock)
--ticks=number of when the counter reach overflow state
*/


;------------start

;---init_timer
init_norm:
    ;just_set_prescaler
    ldi r16, (1<<2)|(1<<0);prscaler: 1023
    out TCCR0B,r16
    ldi r16,0
    out TCNT0,r16
load_ticks:
    ldi r28,78
    ldi r29,0
;-------------main
main:
    sbi DDRB, 5
    sbi PORTB, 5
    call delay
    cbi DDRB, 5
    cbi PORTB, 5
    call delay
    rjmp main

;-----subroutine
delay:
    dec r28
    call timer_
    breq buffer_1
    rjmp carry
buffer_1:
    cpi r29,0x00
    breq buffer_2
    rjmp carry
buffer_2:
    ret
carry:
    sbci r29,0x00
    rjmp delay
timer_:
    sbis TIFR0,0
    rjmp timer_
    cbi TIFR0,0
    ret


The register of the timer0 seems set correctly as a normal mode but the delay doesn't work, and somehow the assembly code generated an infinite loop. The compilation process doesn't generate any error, so I guess the problems are in the delay subroutine definition and the timer init parts.

r28 is set only once. After first delay it becomes 0 and underflows on next dec. Hint: you can implement 16-bit counter arithmetics with subi/sbci.

Also TOV0 flag must be cleared by writing 1 to it, not by clearing bit.
